Comparing two home loans with and without an upfront fee
SMBC Trust Bank PRESTIA in Japan offers two types of floating rate loans:

higher upfront fee (lower interest rate)
lower upfront fee (higher interest rate)

Link: https://www.smbctb.co.jp/en/loan/products/pdf/housing_loan_interest.pdf
For April 2024, I see:

higher upfront fee

Upfront fee: 2.2%, including 10% VAT will be 2.42%
0.34% annual interest rate, paid monthly


lower upfront fee

Upfront fee: 22,000 JPY, including 10% VAT will be 24,200 JPY
0.59% annual interest rate, paid monthly



Casual readers may be shocked by the incredibly low offered interest rates.  Japan has extremely low interest rates compared to other highly developed nations.  (It is a long story.)
Is there a mathematical formula to convert the upfront fee into equivalent running interest rate?  I have some experience with cashflow analysis for bonds/loans, but this formula is a bit tricky for me to derive.  For example: Does loan term (10y/20y/30y) affect the calculation?
For the purpose of this discussion, please assume that interest rate will not change.  That would probably require a Monte Carlo simulation to estimate!

Why does (the second) option 2, "without upfront fee" include an upfront fee of 22,000 yen?

Both total amount and loan term are relevant. (For example, for a loan of 1 million, 2.2% would be 22.000 JPY, e.g. the same fee as the other option, but with a lower rate, which is always better.) Also, the role of VAT is not clear: do you pay VAT also on the interest rates/something else or is it only relevant for the fees (which are then just 2.42% for option 1).

This is a pretty common construct of pre-paid interest (which in the US is called "mortgage points").
Banks offer you a lower interest for an upfront fee so that you don't refinance immediately when interest rate drop but hang on longer to your original mortgage. Whether this makes sense to you or not depends mostly on  how long you are planning to keep that mortgage. If you sell/refinance early, the upfront fee is out of the window and you haven't saved enough interest yet to make up for it.

Is there a mathematical formula to convert the upfront fee into equivalent running interest rate?

Sure. You can calculate a "break even point" that tells how long you need to keep the mortgage to recover the extra fee (as compared to the other option).
You can simply create a payoff schedule for both options and compare how much money you have spent in total it you payoff at month N. Initially this will be more of the higher upfront fee but eventually it will cross over. That's your beak off point.
In order to do this you need to know for each option

Loan amount
Loan term (how many years)
Closing costs
Upfront fee
Interest rate

You may also have to consider tax implications (in the us points can be tax deductible), inflation, cash flow, etc. But for a simple comparison you can probably ignore that
Here is an example assuming a 20M loan over 30 years and roughly your data (excluding VAT)

Initially the "upfront fee option" is more expensive but that changes in the case after about 121 months. This looks like this.
In this example: if you are planning to hang on to the mortgage for 10 years or more, it's better to pay the upfront fee. However the differences here are not super large: in order to net at least 100,000 you would need to keep the mortgage for 13+ years. So if you don't know for sure how long you will have it, personally I would not pay the upfront fee.

EDIT: added formula view


One question: You are calculating "total payments".  That looks like FV (future value) payments.  Don't you need to discount these FV payments (to today) to calculate PV (present value) payments?

@kevinarpe: the total payments are simply the payoff number plus the monthly payments you already made. That's the total money you spent on the loan. If you subtract the original loan amount, this will give you the total cost of loan (disregarding tax and inflation). I've added the formulas I used, but it's always possible I made a mistake. However the ballpark feels correct
